# I can't update a value in a service in Agular 10

Tags: angular

I have 2 components in an Angular app (for learning purposes) and one service.

I want to pass data from component1 to component2 (siblings) and I created a service.

I iterated a hardcoded object array with a `ngFor` and just want to display in the second component the same name I clicked on component 1. it's extremely simple but I'm learning :)

This is the component 1 TS code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DogServiceService } from '../../services/dog-service.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-lista-dog',
  templateUrl: './lista-dog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./lista-dog.component.css']
})
export class ListaDogComponent implements OnInit {

  listaDog = [
    {nombre:"sasha"},
    {nombre:"connie"},
    {nombre:"levi"}
  ]

  constructor(private dogservice:DogServiceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  seeDog(dog){
   this.dogservice.selectedDogForService = dog
  }

}
```

and this is its HTML code:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let dog of listaDog" (click)="seeDog(dog)">{{dog.nombre}}</li>
</ul>
```

This is component 2 TS code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DogServiceService } from '../services/dog-service.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-dog-detail',
  templateUrl: './dog-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dog-detail.component.css']
})
export class DogDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private ds:DogServiceService) { }

  selectedPerrin;  

  ngOnInit() {
    this.selectedPerrin = this.ds.selectedDogForService
  }

}
```

and this is its HTML:

```
<p *ngIf="selectedPerrin">{{selectedPerrin.nombre}}</p>
```

And this is the "service" :)

```
export class DogServiceService {

  selectedDogForService;

  constructor() { }
}
```

I thought that when the user clicked a name in component 1, `seeDog` method would update the value of `selectedDogForService` and angular would detect that change, and `selectedPerrin` variable in component 2 would be updated and then it would update the component 2 view, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

What is the correct approach to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great start! The missing piece here, or the reason why this is not working, is that in the second component, you are initializing the value in the `onInit`, which is a one-time execution. So when the second component loads, the value of `selectedPerrin` is initialized, and it's initialized to `undefined` since that's what the value of `selectedPerrin` is at that point in time.

For this to work, you would need to apply some observables, so that you have a stream of events:

1. In the service, make the `selectedDogForService` a `Subject` or `BehaviorSubject`: `selectedDogForService = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);`
2. In the first component, instead of assigning the value, "push" a new value like so: `this.dogservice.selectedDogForService.next('dog')`.
3. In the second component, use the `async` pipe to read the value:

```
<p *ngIf="selectedPerrin | async">{{ (selectedPerrin | async).nombre }}</p>
```

(code not tested, but should work nonetheless. Use it as a guidepost, and adjust accordingly)